# Java boolean array Initialization and declaration error

Tags: java, backtracking, boolean-expression, n-queens

I was solving famous N-Queen program in java using backtracking.
For checking the conditions for backtracking i declared three boolean arrays,  where
I got complilation error in Boolean array for checking the first condition i.e) Left row boolean array.

Question Link: [N-Queen Problem][1]

````
 class Solution{
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> nQueen(int n) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        
        boolean leftRow[] == new boolean[n];
        boolean leftDiagonal[] = new boolean[2*n];
        boolean rightDiagonal[] = new boolean[2*n];
        
        ArrayList<Integer> curr = new ArrayList<>();
        solve( result,n,0, curr, leftRow, leftDiagonal, rightDiagonal);
        return result;
    }
    
    
    private void solve(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result,int n, int row, ArrayList<Integer> curr, boolean leftRow[], boolean leftDiagonal[],boolean rightDiagonal[]){
        if( row == n){
            result.add(new ArrayList<>(curr));
            return;
        }
        
        for(int col=0; col<n;r++){
            
            if( leftRow[col] || leftDiagonal[row + col] || rightDiagonal[row -col+n])
                continue;
                
            leftRow[col] = leftDiagonal[row+col] = rightDiagonal[row-col+n] = true;
            
            curr.set(col,row+1);
            
            solve(result, n, row+1, curr, leftRow, leftDiagonal, rightDiagonal);
            
            leftRow[col] = leftDiagonal[row+col] = rightDiagonal[row-col+n] = false;

        }
    }
}```


Error
> Compilation Error 

prog.java:41: error: ';' expected
        boolean leftRow[] == new boolean[n];
                         ^
prog.java:41: error: not a statement
        boolean leftRow[] == new boolean[n];
                             ^
2 errors



Thanks in advance :)


  [1]: https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/n-queen-problem0315/1#
````

Comment: can't reproduce the problem here are you sure you saved your file before trying to recompile?

Comment: As a side-note, I'd strongly recommend keeping all the type information together in declarations, e.g. `boolean[] leftRow` instead of `boolean leftRow[]`.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on my side as well. Instead i got the error that `temp` (in `nQueen` method) and `r` (in `solve` method) are undefined.

Comment: r I assume it's row, but what is temp?

Comment: `boolean leftRow[] == new boolean[n];`  is not a valid declaration or statement.

Comment: @iggy Yeah Just now I too found that error. Thanks :)

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS instead of  ``` leftRow = new boolean[n];  leftDiagonal = new boolean[2*n]; rightDiagonal = new boolean[2*n];  ```    Try ``` boolean[] leftRow = new boolean[n];  boolean[] leftDiagonal = new boolean[2*n]; boolean[] rightDiagonal = new boolean[2*n];  ```  Hope it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at this line you might see that u put two equals instead of one:

```java
boolean leftRow[] == new boolean[n];
```

And since this isn't a correct declaration statement it throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the error I found:

1. **Line 5**: You used == instead of =
2. **Line 15**: You can reference only static context from static context (you shuod add static to the method signature
3. Fixed some typos in the code

If you compile this code it will fail, but since I don't know what's the expected outcome, I'm gonna leave it as is

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Tester{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(Solution.nQueen(15));
    }
}

class Solution{
    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> nQueen(int n) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

        boolean leftRow[] = new boolean[n];
        boolean leftDiagonal[] = new boolean[2*n];
        boolean rightDiagonal[] = new boolean[2*n];

        ArrayList<Integer> curr = new ArrayList<>();
        solve( result,n,0, curr, leftRow, leftDiagonal, rightDiagonal);
        return result;
    }


    private static void solve(ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> result,int n, int row, ArrayList<Integer> curr, boolean leftRow[], boolean leftDiagonal[],boolean rightDiagonal[]){
        if( row == n){
            result.add(new ArrayList<>(curr));
            return;
        }

        for(int col=0; col<n;row++){

            if( leftRow[col] || leftDiagonal[col] || rightDiagonal[col])
                continue;

            leftRow[col] = leftDiagonal[col] = rightDiagonal[col] = true;

            curr.set(col,row+1);

            solve(result, n, row+1, curr, leftRow, leftDiagonal, rightDiagonal);

            leftRow[col] = leftDiagonal[col] = rightDiagonal[col] = false;

        }
    }
}
```